# Qt Quick Windows app crashes when C++ try to access element (in range) of a vector

Tags: c++, qt, vector, crash, qml

My Qt Quick application on Windows is experiencing a very weird crash.

I have a `QObject` derived c++ class called `QObjectVector` that allows QML side to access QObject pointers in a container.
On the QML side, I have a bunch of buttons displaying names of objects in that container. when I scroll the mouse wheel, I manually update each button's `currentItem` property.

Strangely, and only *sometimes*, after an *unpredictable* number of fast scrolling, the program crashes (stopped working). After debugging, I found that the crashing happens when the `at` function access `m_data[i]`. I have made sure that `i` is within the valid range [0, `m_data.size()`), so it is not an index-out-of-range error. My guess is that, somehow, the QML engine deletes my objects on the heap when trying to manage memory.

QObjectVector.h

```
#pragma once

#include <QObject>
#include <QVector>

#include "Types.h"

namespace LPP
{
    class QObjectVector : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT

        Q_PROPERTY(Int size READ size NOTIFY sizeChanged)

    public:
        explicit QObjectVector();
        virtual ~QObjectVector();

        Int size();
        Q_INVOKABLE QObject* at(Int);
        void push(QObject*);
        void remove(Int);
        void remove(QObject*);

        QVector<QObject*> &getData();

        bool deleteChildrenOnDestroy;

    private:
        QVector<QObject*> m_data;

    signals:
        void sizeChanged();

    public slots:
    };
}
```

QObjectVector.cpp

```
...
    QObject* QObjectVector::at(Int i)
    {
        qDebug() << "size: " << this->m_data.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < this->m_data.size(); i++){
            qDebug() << "i: " << i << " item: ";
            //when I scroll rapidly, crash happens here when I trace objects in vector
            qDebug() << this->m_data[i];
        }
        qDebug() << "returning.";
        return (i >= 0 && i < this->m_data.size()) ? this->m_data[i] : nullptr;
    }
....
```

ButtonContainer.qml

```
....
    //this function is called when I scroll mouse wheel.
    //itemList contains list of Buttons

    function refreshDisplay() {
        var i, j = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++){
            itemList[i].visible = itemList[i].enabled = false;
        }

        var start = Utils.clamp(Math.floor(scrollView.flickableItem.contentY / (itemHeight + itemVSpacing)), 0, currentFolder.size);
        var end = Utils.clamp(Math.ceil((scrollView.flickableItem.contentY + scrollView.flickableItem.height) / (itemHeight + itemVSpacing)), 0, currentFolder.size);

        var item;

        for (i = start; i < end; i++){
            if (j >= itemList.length){
                itemList.push(tableItem_comp.createObject(tableArea));
            }

            itemList[j].visible = itemList[j].enabled = true;

            item = currentFolder.at(i);
            itemList[j].currentItem = item;
            j++;
        }
    }
....
```

Button.qml

```
....
    property var currentItem: null;

    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.right: parent.right

    SimpleButton {
        id: button
        width: 100
        height: 50
        text: currentItem.name;
        onClicked: {
            viewer.select(currentItem);
        }
    }
....
```

This problem is very weird and unpredictable, and solving it is very crucial to the development of my app, so please please please, any help will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Tommy

Comment: Could you please remove descriptions and post actual codes instead? Stating where the error is in a [MCVE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the objects you're returning are owned by the QML engine, and can therefore be garbage collected at any time.

Try calling

```
QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership(object, QQmlEngine::CppOwnership)
```

on each object before it is returned to QML (e.g. when it's constructed).

See [this section](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#data-ownership) of the documentation:

> When data is transferred from C++ to QML, the ownership of the data always remains with C++. The exception to this rule is when a QObject is returned from an explicit C++ method call: in this case, the QML engine assumes ownership of the object, unless the ownership of the object has explicitly been set to remain with C++ by invoking QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership() with QQmlEngine::CppOwnership specified.
>
> Additionally, the QML engine respects the normal QObject parent ownership semantics of Qt C++ objects, and will not ever take ownership of a QObject instance which already has a parent.

Comment: Alternatively, the objects can be constructed with a parent

Comment: Wow thank you so much! By the way, the problem I was encountering, was it because of the fact that my c++ objects got garbage collected? EDIT: just saw your edit.