# QML - Accessing model data via qml 'var' corrupts the data SIGSEGV

Tags: qt, qml

I have a `QVector<CConfiguration*>` list as datasource for my ListView. I create those objects dynamically and set it as ContextProperty.

```
qmlRegisterUncreatableType<CConfiguration>("DataObjects", 1, 0, "Configuration",QStringLiteral("Configuration should not be created in qml."));
configs.load();
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty(QStringLiteral("configurations"), &configs);
```

Everything good so far. The ListView shows all data fine.
When i now try to access a single data object.

```
var item    = configurationsModel.get(3);
```

this object is later corrupted and gives me a SIGSEGV when i scroll the LIstView after. The get method returns a CConfiuration*

Thanks for ideas or help

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35863560/qt-qml-c-program-crash-on-access-a-qlist-from-qml/35873170#35873170 / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38592752/qt-quick-windows-app-crashes-when-c-try-to-access-element-in-range-of-a-vect/38592961#38592961.

Comment: I'd encourage you to implement a proper data model.

Comment: @dtech, what is a "proper data model"?

Comment: Can you be more specific on "proper data model" ?
I am always happy to learn something new.

Comment: In your case - a subclass of `QAbstractListModel`. An object that was intended to be used as a model, with all the necessary bells and whistles. In the case of `QObject` derived items there are many ready to use implementations - just search around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having seen your code, I would guess that the problem you're seeing is [one of ownership](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#data-ownership):

> When data is transferred from C++ to QML, the ownership of the data
>   always remains with C++. **The exception to this rule is when a QObject
>   is returned from an explicit C++ method call**: in this case, the QML
>   engine assumes ownership of the object, unless the ownership of the
>   object has explicitly been set to remain with C++ by invoking
>   QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership() with QQmlEngine::CppOwnership
>   specified.
>
> Additionally, the QML engine respects the normal QObject parent
>   ownership semantics of Qt C++ objects, and will never delete a QObject
>   instance which has a parent.

The fix is to either set the ownership explicitly:

```
QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership(&configs, QQmlEngine::CppOwnership);
```

Or give the object a parent (after allocating it on the heap):

```
Configs *config = new Configs(&application);
configs->setParent(&application)
```

Regardless of which option you choose, it has to be done before the context property is set and the application's QML is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am new to qml so i was not familiar with the concept of ownership transfer. 
The 1st approach (explicit set ownership) DID NOT solve the probelm.
The 2nd approch (setting parent relationships) DID work.

Comment: I am still a bit unsure when to create my objects on the stack and when it is neccessarx to put them on the heap to make Qt / QML happy.
Is there some documentation about this topic?

Comment: Actually, setting ownership is the one solution known to work, objects with parents are known to be accidentally deleted by the qml engine while still in use when used in conjunction with models, a bug that was just recently fixed but will not be out until qt 5.12 is released, probably around the end of the year - https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-50319

Comment: 3rd day now without crash. I think this was the solution. @Mitch: you have great experience with Qt/qml. Maybe you could have a look on my other problem too - please ;-)

Comment: I have very little experience with threading unfortunately, so I won't be much help there.